# Change of subject in respect of "in order to"

Tags: meaning, grammar

"In order to" or the shortened version "to" always require that the subject of the main clause and subordinate clause are the same (cf. https://englishstudypage.com/grammar/using-in-order-to-in-english/), right? In order to change the subject, I would need "in order that" or "in order for ... to" (sort of object complement).

The following sentence:

> Sensors require maintenance in order to clean the lenses from fouling

wouldn't make much sense, I guess, as it would mean that "once sensors received maintenance, the sensors can clean their lenses (themselves)"

I would need to write either:

> Sensors require maintenance in order for the lenses to be cleaned from fouling

or

> Sensors require maintenance in order that lenses are cleaned from fouling

Is this understanding correct?

I guess the same applies to situations where the main clause is in the passive voice meaning that the 'subject' of the passive main clause needs to be the subject of the subordinate clause introduced by 'in order to'.

But, I can't help myself in thinking that the following sentence is correct even though the above logic doesn't apply:

> The signal is sampled with a data acquisition system in order to make it processable with a computer for calculating the TOA data

The only way I can explain this to me is that the subject of the active voice version of the main clause would be the same as the subject in the 'in order to' clause (I sample the signal and I make it processable).

Comment: ***Syntactically***, your first example can be parsed in either of two ways. Both (1) What the sensors require is the specific type of maintenance intended to clean the lenses, or (2) The reason sensors require any maintenance at all is because that will ensure the lenses are cleaned. But ***semantically*** there's not really much point in trying to distinguish the two parsings with your *exact* example.

Comment: Thank you FumbleFingers, so I guess the rule of the subject of the main clause being the same as the "hidden subject" in the subordinate clause is less strict...

Comment: I'm not sure (not implying disagreement; I don't know how strict you thought "the rule" was before asking here). I thought there might be earlier questions about this potential syntactic ambiguity (where the two different ***parsings*** might lead to more obviously different ***meanings***), but I can't find any. My guess is the ***[in order] to...*** clause is an adverbial element that could optionally be seen as a ***sentence adverb*** if that makes more sense than simply applying it to the nearest preceding element that's syntactically credible. Dunno if that perspective helps, though.

Comment: Your native speaker perspective helps a lot!:-) I infer from here "simply applying it to the nearest preceding element that's syntactically credible" that the reader should read with common sense and understand that "in order to/to" highlights the purpose why "x is done/necessary/applied/...". Otherwise, choosing 'in order that + subject' or 'in order for y to' would make the sentence quite "heavy" and disturb the reading flow. I've never thought about this issue before and it just came up and confused me massively.

Comment: @FumbleFingers for reassurance: Would you say that your logic also applies to this sentence? "Transient and aperiodic blade vibrations require a time-dependent spectrum analysis so as to detect those vibration parameters that are relevant to a particular time window." (Neither analysis nor vibrations can "detect", it's a person who is able to do so; I would expect a reader to draw this conclusion)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: another example would be: "Real capacitive waveforms that had been generated during an experiment on a transonic compressor were replicated to develop a sensor model for the simulation"

Comment: Both those examples are fairly complicated, but that's just because *they contain a lot of information*. I'd say your phrasing is as good as any native speaker would be likely to come up with (and many would struggle to do as well). But as an ultra-simplified context, it might help to consider ***She asked him to help me***, which would normally be parsed as *"helping me" is what she asked **him** to do*, but it could be that she asked him some contextually-identified question ***for my benefit*** (perhaps because he's Spanish, and I don't speak that language very well).

Comment: Thank you @FumbleFingers! That was helpful and insightful:-)